# How to remove this toilet supply line that seems to have no nut?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

The toilet water supply doesn't seem to have a nut at all and rotating it or turning it does nothing. Unsure how to remove this:

[image]

Comment: Have you pulled that bevelled white cover back - there may be a nut under there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That valve seems to be of the variety where **the supply line and stop-valve are a single integrated unit**. In the foggy haze of past bad ideas, this was not uncommon (although most that I encounter are metal).

You will need to shut off the cold water supply and replace the valve and flex supply line...